# Copy pasting to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a cell whenever a changed is made on a specific cell. I have the vba codes below but it has an error. Thank you

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = Range("SalesStage").Column Then
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("TC").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(1) = Now
        Range("CID").Rows(Target.Row).Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("TC").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(, 1)
        Range("SalesStage").Rows(Target.Row).Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("TC").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(, 2)
    End If

End Sub
```

I'm trying to copy then paste a cell to another worksheet. Also, if I can copy the contents only and not the cell format. Thank you.

Comment: What's the defined names (SalesStage, CID ..)? What's the error?

Comment: Those are column names, and the error is after I changed a cell in SalesStage (column) the excel restarts.

Comment: To clarify; here's the my code.

    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

        If Target.Column = Range("D1:D1000").Column Then
        
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1:B1000").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(1) = Now
            Range("B1:B1000").Rows(Target.Row).Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1:B1000").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(, 1)
            Range("D1:D1000").Rows(Target.Row).Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B1:B1000").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(, 2)
        End If
    
    End Sub

Comment: *it has an error* is meaningless unless you include information about the error. You got an error message, which you failed to provide in your question. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. There is no excuse for not providing that detail in your question to make it available to us. Also, do not add information in the comments, where it gets lost in the clutter. Instead, [edit] your question and add it there, where it belongs and where it can be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you. I found a code that works for my project.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    Dim aCell As Range, c As Range
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set c = Intersect(Range("C3:C502"), Target)
    
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "BPA2024"
        For Each aCell In c
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 38).Locked = (Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) = 0)
        Next
        ActiveSheet.Protect "BPA2024"
    End If
    
    If Target.Column = Range("R1").Column Then
        Worksheets("ChangeLog").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(1) = Now
        Worksheets("ChangeLog").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(, 1).Value = Range("C1").Rows(Target.Row).Value
        Worksheets("ChangeLog").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(, 2).Value = Range("R1").Rows(Target.Row).Value
    End If
    
    If Target.Column = Range("S1").Column Then
        Worksheets("ChangeLog").Range("F1").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(1) = Now
        Worksheets("ChangeLog").Range("F1").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(, 1).Value = Range("C1").Rows(Target.Row).Value
        Worksheets("ChangeLog").Range("F1").End(xlDown).Rows.End(xlDown).Offset(, 2).Value = Range("S1").Rows(Target.Row).Value
    End If
        
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `EnableEvents = False` before changing cells to avoid recursive event triggers that crash Excel

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        Dim c As Range
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Worksheets("Sheet3")
            If .Range("B1").Value = "" Then
                Set c = .Range("B1")
            Else
                Set c = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        End With
        c.Value = Now
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Offset(0, -2).Value
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Application.EnableEvents property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Thank you for this. But the excel still crashed when I change a cell in column D. What I'd like to is to monitor the changes in a worksheet and timestamp when the changes are made.

Comment: I would suggest to test the code with a new workbook first.  Sheet3 is a must-have sheet in the workbook.